# How to get sublist from Arraylist of objects?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have to get a List of strings from a List of Objects, and I don't think looping through it is the best way.

**Explanation:**

With Person being:

```
public class Person{
    String name;
    String id;
}
```

I have a List of  as parameter to a method

```
public List<String> getNames(ArrayList<Person> people){}
```

And I want the list of names in the list of people

what's the best way to do that without looping and adding to another List?

Comment: Why don't you want a `List<String` to be returned?

Comment: I do, just forgot to put it on the method declaration, already edited it, thanks!

Comment: Next question would be why not loop over? It will be done regardless which approach you want to take.

Comment: actually I always do it by looping, but I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it

Comment: @CarlosMion in which case you mean you’ve always “externally” iterated over the collection. Like Murat mentioned whichever approach you take there will be some sort of iteration whether that is internal iteration (which is what you seem to be looking for) or external iteration (which seems like is what you want to avoid).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowed to use java 8 in android you can simply do a `map` over your list:

```
public List<String> getNames(ArrayList<Person> people){
    return people.stream().map(a -> a.name).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: You can use ``retrolambda``, It is quite popular : https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda

Comment: +1 for Stream and Lambda. OP should use Java8 or just iterate over his List. There's nothing wrong about looping.

Comment: @JohnDoe OP is using android and most likely below the min API level for the stream api.

Comment: exactly, I'm programming for corporate old devices

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Person{
    String name;
    String id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In methods

```
public List<String> getNames(ArrayList<Person> people){
    return Arrays.asList((people.toString().replace("[","").replace("]","")).split(Pattern.quote(",")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the answer you're looking for:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.DeeptoString(people))
```

Comment: and how do I decide which String from the Object to get?

Comment: If you add each variable to separate array lists prior to calling your method, you can simply println the list to console (as shown above). If not, however, the easiest method would be to loop and then choose the variable to display.

Answer (score 0):

> what's the best way to do that without looping and adding to another List?

Converting one `Iterable` to another `Iterable` will involve looping.

You could store the names in another `ArrayList<String>` while creating original `ArrayList<Person>` but the advantage over simply looping over `Person`s is highly questionable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to iterate over `List<Persons> people` you could create a view on the list, which will show a `Person` in a specific way.

```
public class ListView<L, T> extends AbstractList<T> {

    private List<L> original;
    private Mapper<L, T> mapper;

    private ListView(List<L> original, Mapper<L, T> mapper) {
        this.original = original;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return mapper.map(original.get(index));
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return original.size();
    }

    private static <L, T> ListView<L, T> of(List<L> original, Mapper<L, T> mapper) {
        return new ListView<>(original, mapper);
    }

}
```

A `Mapper` is an interface and defines how we want to view a `Person`.

```
private static abstract interface Mapper<I, O> {

    O map(I input);

}
```

Now we can use this to implement `getNames`:

```
public List<String> getNames(ArrayList<Person> people) {
    return ListView.of(people, new Mapper<Person, String>() {

        @Override
        public String map(Person person) {
            return person.getName();
        }
    });
}
```

Applied to an example:

```
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new Person("Micky", "1"), new Person("Donald", "2"), new Person("Daisy", "3")));
List<String> names = getNames(people);
System.out.println(names); // [Micky, Donald, Daisy]
```

Please note: The shown implementation of `ListView` does not support modification. Thus it's a read only `List`. If you don't want to add a name without adding a `Person` then this implementation should be sufficient.

Using Java 8 would result in much simpler code. But you [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53520201/how-to-get-sublist-from-arraylist-of-objects-in-java#comment93909188_53520297) you cannot. Thus this approach without Java 8 features.